# How to find out an unknown PC Server's IP without Monitor

Tags: windows-vista, windows-server-2003, ip-address

I have a PC Server running but without a monitor. The OS is Windows Server 2003. I can connect my laptop to its network interface. How can I find out its IP?

Answer (score 2):

If you've a router kicking about you could connect both the laptop and server to that, then just look at the router's admin pages to see the list of DHCP clients (and thus the Server's IP in this context).

This might already be possible depending of your current network configuration (ie, just check the DHCP server), unless of course the server *provides* the DHCP for you network in which case this suggestion is useless...

Comment: ... assuming the server uses dhcp at all. might be static.

Comment: @Sirex Another very valid catch with this as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected through the network interface, you might be able to find the IP address by doing a port scan with something like NMap. There is a windows version [here](http://nmap.org/download.html) that you can put on your laptop.

Comment: to do this: connect a crossover wire to it from your laptop, - set your laptop to a similar ip address (example: if you know its something a bit like 192.168.0.1, set the laptop to .200 Then do nmap -sP 192.168.0.1-255 and see which ip's are live. (might be worth doing it twice with 2 laptop ip's just in case you picked the same one and clashed).

Answer (score 1):

Right after you start your computer run `arp -a` from the command line. Assuming your computer and server are on the same subnet.

Answer (score -1):

- Do one thing connect your laptop with your server and use some software ip-address scanner like  [Advanced IP Scanner 1.5](http://www.radmin.com/products/utilities/ipscanner.php) . Its free too
- How do you expect to work without seeing it visually. Anyways when I face something like this, I do it using several shortcut keys and trying to imagine whats happening and then finally take a print-screen. Then I paste the print-screen in a bitmap and and take Print (its hard to do it sometimes when you are blind).
- Or get a temporary monitor